# Moore-Penrose inverse of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, block-matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $L$ be a symmetric block matrix written as

$$L = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta e_{n}' & \gamma e_n'\\
\beta e_{n} & A & B \\
\gamma e_n & B' & C
\end{array} \right]$$

Is there any way to find the Moore-Penrose inverse (pseudoinverse) $L^\dagger$ of $L$ as a block matrix such that the blocks of $L^\dagger$ are expressed in terms of blocks of $L$?

Here, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are scalars, $A$, $C$ are square symmetric matrices and $e_n$ denotes the $n \times 1$ vector of all ones. Further, $'$ is used to denote the transpose of a matrix.

Any suggestions/hints will be beneficial. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For this, it would suffice to find the block $2\times2$ pseudoinverse of a symmetric matrix. There are formulas for the inverse when one of the two diagonal blocks are invertible - perhaps the derivations of these can be modified for pseudoinverses.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The matrix in question here resembles a Laplacian like matrix corresponding to Gear graphs.